# C# data types and variables

Tags: c#

I need to pass the value of `spyagencytb.text` in `SpyForm` to the variable `SpyAgency`, but before I can do that there have to be some form of implicit conversion from type `String` to type `Agency`.

```
namespace Day3Homework
{

    class Spy
    {
        SpyForm form = new SpyForm(); //creating an instance of the SpyForm 

        private string codeName;
        private Agency spyAgency;
        private DateTime dateLastSeen;
        private string notes;

        public string CodeName
        {
            get { return codeName; }
            set { codeName = value; }
        }

        public Agency SpyAgency
        {
            get { return spyAgency; }
            set { spyAgency = value; }
        }

     public DateTime DateLastSeen
        {
            get { return dateLastSeen; }
            set { dateLastSeen = DateTime.Parse(form.textBox5.Text); }
        }
}
```

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding how properties work.  Your model class should not reference the form at all.

Comment: "Nothing seems to work." - what have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: since this is `HomeWork` perhaps you should go back to the instructor and have them explain and or go over again the assignment lessons prior to this ask them to explain where and how to create Instance of Class Objects. you can't expect us to complete your homework assignment for you.

Comment: What text is entered into the text box?  And how is that text used to create an `Agency`.  You probably don;t want an implicit conversion but some sort of mapping or constructor that you use to create the `Agency`.

Comment: all am trying to do is to save the input of the user to the *Agency* variable.The text entered into the box is the Agency Name say "CIA".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SLaks is correct; you are creating a private `SpyForm`, which is never updated and is not available to the user or anything else, inside every `Spy` instance. Completely wrong. Remove this:

```
SpyForm form = new SpyForm(); //creating an instance of the SpyForm
```

Change your `DateLastSeen.set` to this:

```
set { dateLastSeen = value; }
```

Then somewhere in your `SpyForm` code you will do something like this:

```
this.someSpy = new Spy();
```

and in one of your form events you will do something like this:

```
DateTime d;
if DateTime.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out d)
    this.someSpy.DateLastSeen = d;
else you need to tell the user the date was invalid;
```

There are a few other mistakes in this code; you should not be defining your own backing fields, you should define a constructor that initializes all your properties, and you should avoid embedding the data types in the names of variables, but those will not make your program incorrect.

Comment: thank you very much...it was very helpful